# Visual Studio 2010 Installation

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework, visual-studio-2010

Ok, so I have installed a copy of VS2010 Professional but suppose I want to get Ultimate or even Premium. How would I install it such that it upgrades rather than a new program?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to upgrade Visual Studio editions.

However, I was in same situation and uninstalling one version and installing another works without problems if you remember to save your settings (Tools -> Import and Export Settings).

Comment: Yeah, it's easier to just jump to Ultimate and don't install the features that you won't use, instead of doing the upgrade dance...

Comment: @Joe This is purely matter of cost. I assume that he wants Professional since it is cheaper and he is only thinking about getting Ultimate if he really needs it.

Comment: I figured he was using MSDN or Microsoft's student program, where you have the option to download any version.